# Why does Blowfish and RC4 (Arc4) make same encrypted strings

Tags: rc4, blowfish

I made a program on android. I used a password key of "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1" for both of them as a key. The program i made was using Android java Cipher library. When I encrypt and decrypt with blowfish and arc4 its works, and vise versa works as well. Are they supposted to do that. Did I implement the algorithms correctly?

Comment: Can you be more specific? You can use a (say) 128-bit key for Blowfish or for RC4. If you encrypt a plaintext with Blowfish and decrypt the ciphertext with Blowfish, you'll get the same plaintext back. Likewise if you encrypt/decrypt with RC4. It's not a good _idea_ to use the same key for two different purposes (or to use the archaic and broken Blowfish or RC4 at all), but to give an answer, Blowfish doesn't care if you use the same key for RC4 independently. However, if you can ‘encrypt with Blowfish’ and ‘decrypt with RC4’ and get the original plaintext back, something is terribly wrong.

Comment: I am doing the encryption and decryption as a research into different crypto techniques. I firstly make a input password into bytes using "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1". Then pass the same keyto AES Blowfish and RC4. I am keeping the key the same to show how different algorithms are. When I use Blowfish and RC4 my Base64 output string is the same for both algorithms. And I am slightly confused why is that? When i use AES the encrypted output is different.

Comment: This sounds like a programming problem, not a cryptography problem.  For a fixed message and key, there is a negligible probability that the ciphertext for that message under that key using RC4 is the same as the ciphertext for that message under that key using _any_ message encryption scheme derived from Blowfish (CTR, CBC, whatever).

Comment: You were correct, one of my GUI buttons invoked a wrong method which lead to Blowfish encrypt method to be called, instead of RC4.  I guess its my fault for assuming ciphering technique problem, even though I remember checking all the GUI buttons calling right methods. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

> Did I implement the algorithms correctly?

given that

> one of my GUI buttons invoked a wrong method which lead to Blowfish
>   encrypt method to be called, instead of RC4

we don't know. But ARC4 working correctly with Blowfish ciphertexts and vice-versa certainly doesn't make sense cryptographically speaking, espeically since they are two *very* different encryption schemes.